# Translate mathematical function into R

Tags: r

I have this mathematical function

[image]

I have written R code:

```
result <- 0
    for (i in length(v)) {
        result <- abs(x-v[i])
    }
    return(result)
```

to compute the function.

However, this does not seems efficient to me? How to implement this `sum` with the R `sum()` function?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum(abs(x-v))` show be enough, no need the `for` loop, since arithmetic operations in R are vectorized

```
# Example
> x <- 5
> v <- 1:10
> abs(x-v)
 [1] 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5
> sum(abs(x-v))
[1] 25
```